# How to manually add control variable for Controls such as Edit control and use it, without using wizard?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

For some reason "Add Control Variable" wizard doesn't work in my Visual Studio setup ("Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019", Version 16.1.16).

So, how to access controls in code? What are the manual code steps needed to setup  say, Edit Control, and access its data?

Comment: This happens to me too.  If you create a new project and add a variable through wizard there you will see the code needed. Microsoft told me to delete the dialog and add it again to the project. But that sounds like a nightmare. Why can’t the wizards simply work. Grrh...

Comment: Since Visual studio 6 MFC wizards were getting worse with each release. I've abandoned them and do everything by hand.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you want to bind a control variable to a (dialog) control, or do you want to bind a variable that reflects the actual control contents? @jab: That's incorrect. After Visual Studio 6, there was no MFC class wizard in VS 2002, 2003, 2005, and 2008. It reappeared in VS 2010 with *greatly* improved code synchronization. No longer did you have to honor the generated code comments, or care about where you write *your* code. It was further improved with VS 2012, and only started to decay around VS 2015/2017.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple steps to add your own controls and handlers manually.

**MyDlg.h**

```
public:
   CButton m_Button;                    // your control
protected:
   virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);  // declare the data exchange support
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()             // your message map
public:
   afx_msg void OnBnClickedMyButton();  // your message handler
```

**MyDlg.cpp**

```
// do data exchange between your variable and the control
void MyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, ID_BTN, m_Button);
}
// map your message with handler
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(ID_BTN, &MyDlg::OnBnClickedMyButton)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL MyDlg::OnInitDialog(){
    /* … */
    m_Button.Create(L"Click-Me", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, RECT{ 0,0,100,100 }, this, ID_BTN);
    m_Button.ShowWindow(true);
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `m_Button.Create` if the button is defined in the dialog resource with `ID_BTN`. OTOH If you manually `Create()` the button, then there is no need for the data exchange stuff.